# importar tabla .sql con sql managment 2016

Tags: sql-server

Tengo 6 tablas desde en una base oracle 8i, y y necesito insertarlas en otra base SQL 2016.
Por el lado de oracle use una utilidad llamada Toad , me permitió mediante Data Export, exportar cada una de las tablas a un formato .sql  Necesito ayuda como poder incorporar esas tablas mediante Sql managment a una base Sql Server . Cada tabla se llama por ej. tabla1.sql , tabla2.sql, etc . Lo ideal seria poder importarlas como tablas, pero no es problemas si tengo que crear las tablas y luego importar los registros. Ayuda por favor, necesito importarlas.

Finalmente encontré una forma, quisiera saber si es correcta, y si se puede optimizar :

```
INSERT INTO HISTORICO ( FEC_1, FEC_2, HORA, NUM_NIVEL, NUM_AREA, DEPOSITO,ID_VEN, ID_IDEN ) VALUES (
CONVERT(DATETIME,'04/29/2008', 111), 
CONVERT(DATETIME,'04/29/2008', 111), 
CONVERT(DATETIME,'12/30/2018 07:59:00 PM', 20),2402, 2197, 24030, 1, 434);
```

Comment: Si el script no contiene creación de tablas, crea las tablas, abres el .sql que tiene los inserts en el management studio y lo ejecutas. Con suerte correrá. si no corre, entonces seria de ver qué mensaje de error o problema te está dando, pero la sentencia del insert es bastante estándar, a menos que tengas datos binarios o algún otro tipo no estándar en Oracle.

Comment: si ok. Estaba viendo el script y tiene todos los insert into de cada registro. El problema es que 4 de las 6 campos son de fecha , del estilo to_date ... se te ocurre como solucionarlo ?

Comment: Con un par de sustitución de texto sale, `to_date('14/11/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY')` se convierte en `cast('14/11/2021' as date)` o en `convert(date, '14/11/2021', 103)`, por poner ejemplos.  Sobre todo, se facilita si el editor que uses tiene búsqueda y sustitución de expresiones regulares (muchos editores la tienen).

Comment: Buenisimo. Estoy usando visual code que imagino es uno de los mas usados , podrias dame una idea como deberia configurar search y replace ? tengo cantidad de registros similares a :

INSERT INTO  HISTORICO ( FEC_CONS, FEC_COMER, HOR_CONS, NUM_CARD, NUM_LEGA, CEN_COST,
CRE_CONS, ID_IDEN ) VALUES ( 
 TO_Date( '04/29/2008 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),  TO_Date( '04/29/2008 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
,  TO_Date( '12/30/1899 08:05:00 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'), 2940, 2407, 24040
, 1, 416);

Comment: No existe ningún estilo para ese formato de fecha en [`convert()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), sugiero que intentes exportarlo con otro formato y si no se puede, mira si con sustituciones de texto logras acercarte al estilo 100: `mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)` (es lo que yo haría) Un saludo.

Comment: ok, una mas , probe la siguiente sentencia y me da error de sintaxis. Me puedes aclarar porque falla ? :
INSERT INTO BASE_HISTORICO ( FEC_CONS, FEC_COMER, HOR_CONS, NUM_CARD, NUM_LEGA, CEN_COST,CRE_CONS, ID_IDEN ) 
VALUES (( CONVERT(DATE,( '04/29/2008', 20)), CONVERT(DATE,( '04/29/2008', 20)), CONVERT(DATE,( '12/30/1899 07:59:00 PM', 20),2402, 2197, 24030, 1, 434))

Comment: Si pones eso en la pregunta, con gusto te explico un par de cosas que veo, aunque no traigo un parser integrado :D